# ConTeXt using the tex-context package in pkgsrc

Tags: context

The cross-platform package manager pkgsrc includes a ConTeXt package, http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/print/tex-context/README.html

Has anyone used this successfully? I have separately installed ConTeXt minimals and pkgsrc on the same computer, but I've only been able to compile ConTeXt documents with ConTeXt minimals. [Lua|PDF|Xe]LaTeX is functional in pkgsrc.

***Edit***
Newer versions of pkgsrc have fixed the problem. They put a working `context` executable in the pkgsrc-managed `bin` directory and everything else in the pkgsrc-managed `share/texmf-dist` directory.

Comment: What happens when you compile a document using context from pgksrc?

Comment: The package does not include a "context" executable script in the usual directory in the system `$PATH` (typically `/usr/pkg/bin` for a pkgsrc-based system), so the obvious guess is the file `/usr/pkg/share/texmf-dist/scripts/context/stubs/unix/context`, which seems to be a shell script. Running this (with `/bin/sh`) results in complaints about mtxrun not being found, but adding the directory (`/usr/pkg/share/texmf-dist/scripts/context/stubs/unix`) to $`PATH` results in complaints about mtxrun not being executable. Perhaps just a permissions error (+ lack of a `/usr/pkg/bin/context` script).

Comment: `context` is just a wrapper around `mtxrun` and `mtxrun` needs to be executable in order for the rest of the machinery to work. All the stubs from `.../stubs/unix` should be executable and in `$PATH`.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: Yes. More recent versions of pkgsrc do include a context executable, and it seems work properly (true for pkgsrc-2017Q4).